# How to compare strings that were created by substring?

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm wondering why it doesn't work, and why I cant't use the CHAR data type for variables a and b. The point is, how to compare the first and the last digits of number (pr) accordingly such way.

```
String  a, b;
for (int i=100; i<1000;i++) {
    for (int j=100; j<1000;j++) {
        pr=j*i;
        a = String.valueOf(pr).substring(0, 1);
        b= String.valueOf(pr).substring(4, 5);

        if ((a==b) )  {
            System.out.println(pr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use "char" datatype, append charAt().

Comment: Technically he could cast an int to char as long as it was smaller than 2^15-1 (to get the expected result).... Bad practice, but legal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `equals` functions
`a.equals(b)`

If you want to ignore case then use
`a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)`

Comment: It is not clear why case matters for numerals?

Comment: @merlin2011 It's about Objects, not numerals http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311451/difference-between-equals-and-instanceof

Comment: as he mentioned its a string.. so just to give him idea that something of ignoring case is also possible.. so in future it will help him

Answer (score 1):

This is not JavaScript to use `==` for String comparison.

Go for [equals method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Really? If only if this wasn't a dupe and someone hadn't already posted that over five minutes ago ....

Answer (score 1):

In Java, operator `==` compares object identities, so if there are two objects of type String with the same content, `==` will return false for them:

```
String x = new String ("foo");
String y = new String ("bar");
if (x == y)
    System.out.println ("Equal");
else
    System.out.println ("Now equal"); // This will be printed
```

In order to compare String object by content, not by identity, you need to use `equals()` method like this:

```
if (x.equals (y))
    System.out.println ("Equal"); // This will be printed
else
    System.out.println ("Now equal");
```

Note, that if `x` is `null`, then `x.equals (y)` will throw `NullPointerException` while `x == y` will return `false` if `y` is not `null` and `true` if `y` is `null`.  To prevent `NullPointerException` you need to do something like this:

```
if (x == null && y == null || x != null && x.equals (y))
    System.out.println ("Equal"); // This will be printed
else
    System.out.println ("Now equal");
```